# why is npx react-native run-android Not working on my windows

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, sdk, react-native-cli

[image: this is the picture of the error]Hello friends pls I have been stuck on this   error for the past weeks I'm trying to run a React native cli project on my Windows laptop and after following the documentation on the official create React native website I still get this error I have already downloaded and installed my android studio and my virtual device is up and running but for some reason I whenever I try to run "npx react-native run-android " after a while this error shows up

This my first working on a React native cli project
I ran npx react-native init app3
And

I have configured my Path and Android_Home environment variables as you can see it's still showing on my command prompt and powershell

I'm using a

Node version 16.13.0
Npm version 8.1.0
Javac version 17.0.1

And I'm relatively new to mobile development

Is used the the

```
Echo %ANDROID_HOME%
echo %PATH%
```

Command to check the Android_Home And Path location on my system
And it was as follows

C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools